# How do can you get the roster of a Jabber user with simple-xmpp/node-xmpp?

Tags: node.js, xmpp, openfire, webrtc

I'm using the 'simple-xmpp' module and I'm trying to get the roster of a Jabber user after he is logged in. Connecting to the Jabber server (Openfire in my case) and sending messages works just fine. When I try to do a xmpp.getRoster() call it simply returns 'undefined'.

Here's my code. I imagine that I should get some sort of JSON object. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
var config = require('../lib/config');
var xmpp = require('simple-xmpp');

xmpp.on('online', function() {
  console.log('Yes, I\'m connected!');

  console.log(xmpp.getRoster());
});

xmpp.on('error', function(err) {
   console.error(err);
});

xmpp.on('chat', function(from, message) {
console.log(from + " said: " + message);
});


exports.connect = function (username, password) {
   xmpp.connect({
       jid         : username,
       password    : password,
       host        : config.jabberHost,
       port        : config.jabberPort
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled on it looking for something else.

I did it by using node-xmpp-client and ltx from node-xmpp-core and sending the following:

```
client.send(new ltx.Element('iq', { from: 'user@domain.com', type:'get', id:'roster_1'})
    .c('query', { xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster' }).t().up()
  )
  )
```